# SQL Query building with calling stored procedure and using fixed values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, export

I'm trying to initiate an export from one location to another.

This query I'm trying to build needs to make sure export goes automatic after doing a select to search on records, instead of in the client (gui) manually searching for each of them and right click export to.

The strings I entered are fixed the select is from the databases.

The stored procedure is called `CreateExportWorkItem`.

```
SELECT 
    'exec '+ 'http://' +  picHost + '/' + picUrl as piclocation, stat.number, stat.humid, stat.picDateTime as datetime
FROM
    defaultclinical.dbo.vwSwpicLocation as loc
JOIN
    defaultstatistics.dbo.receivedpics as stat ON stat.picuid = loc.picuid
WHERE 
    loc.picUid IN (SELECT picUID 
                   FROM defaultStatistics.dbo.ReceivedPics
                   WHERE OrganizationId IN ('SVH', 'RES')
                     AND ReceivedDateTime BETWEEN '2017-03-20 19:28:14.845' AND '2017-03-23 03:56:23.620')
                     AND picHost like 'server12%',

@CreatedUserName='administrator',
@remoteIpAddress='192.168.15.20',
@remotePort='80',
@remoteNumberOfConcurrentRequests='2',
@remoteResendpicOnRetry='0',
@remoteKeepConnectionAcrosspics='0',
@remoteBsnExport='0',
@MaxRetries='1',
@RetryDelay='10',
@Priority='0',
@locationAffinity='Main Location'
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Help on what exactly? did you missed a question here

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi, 
@ Jarlh, I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: HI, @Rahul, sorry for the bad explanation of the question. 
The question is.
I have a working Select. and I have strings with fixed values.
How to combine the 2 so that i can do the "Select exec CreateExportWorkItem"  storedprocedure.